# How to deal with classcasting Java x Scala?

Tags: java, scala, inheritance

I'm having a problem using Scala x Java.

To contextualize you about the situation let me put a quick example:

- Java Class

```java
public class Animal {
}
```

- Java Class

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

- Scala class

```scala
class Dog extends Animal {
}
```

- Java class

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal1 = new Dog(); //Java's Animal receives Scala's Dog reference
    Animal animal2 = new Cat(); //Java's Animal receives a Java's Cat reference
  }
}
```

I'm receiving an error message like:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Dog to Animal
```

But the same doesn't happens to the class Cat.

Someone could kindly explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Not reproducible. Compiles just fine. Seems that you've oversimplified your problem into nonexistence.

Comment: Which version of scala and java are you using ? Even I am not getting any error

Comment: Hi! I'm using Scala 2.11.0.

The weird is that is happenin in my Eclipse IDE. I'll re-review my build path to check if everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work when using the following versions of JDK and Scala: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I rebooted my computer and it worked. Looks like I was with an issue in my classpath.